# Сортировка лексикографически

Tags: php

Подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать аналог `sort($array, SORT_STRING )`, не использую эту встроенную функцию?
Я уже задавал похожий вопрос, но тогда, решил, что смогу всё сделать, однако в итоге сортируется не всегда правильно, я написал следующее

```
for($i=1;$i<=$_POST["quantity"];$i++){
    $array[$i]=$i;
    };

for ($j = 0; $j < count($array) + 1; $j++){
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($array) - $j - 1; $i++){
            if (strcmp($array[$i],$array[$i + 1]) == 1){
            $tmp_var = $array[$i + 1];
            $array[$i + 1] = $array[$i];
            $array[$i] = $tmp_var;
        };
    };
};
```

думал это будет одно и тоже что и sort, но ... не работает и всё тут.. подскажите, что не так? при вводе массива с 1 до 11 выдаёт не
**1 10 *11* 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9,** а **1 10 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 *11***

Comment: у меня правильно выдает =)  `1 10 11 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9`

Comment: добавил верхние три строки.. может в них дело?

Comment: внутренний цикл обычно с `j+1` начинают

Answer (score 0, accepted):

При построении массива вы начинаете с ключа `1`:

```
for($i=1; ...
```

А при сортировке с `0`.

```
for ($j = 0; $j < count($array) + 1; $j++){
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($array) - $j - 1; $i++){
```

Укажите `$i=0` здесь: `for($i=0;$i<=$_POST["quantity"];$i++){`

Comment: Спасибо, мои невнимательность и отсутствие опыта - зло =)